# Java inserting variables of objects to array

Tags: java, arrays, object

I searched everywhere but I couldn't find anything. Let's think we have a student class and this class has two variables:name and grade. I want to insert names of the created objects to an array(Only array no arraylist). How can I do this?

```
public class Student {

    String name;
    int grade;
    public Student(String name, int grade) {
        this.name=name;
        this.grade=grade;
    }
   public String toString()
   {
       return "name:"+this.name+"grade:"+this.grade;
   }
}

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
           Student s1=new Student("Jason",73);
           Student s2=new Student("Ricky",64);
           Student s3=new Student("Mark",53);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's up with your indentation?

Comment: I think h phil wants to iterate over his students and store the ages in an array. Steps: Create an new array of type String. Store your students in an array of type Student. Then use a for loop to iterate over your students. Then just store the namr of your student in your String array. This is very basic and you should google each step it will help you to figure out how to proceed each step by yourself...Also read about getters and setters :)

Comment: "I searched everywhere" so you say. But how can we believe you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is always a good practice to return value of your attributes through a getter. Create a getter method in Student class and access it to get the names

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int grade;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Student(String name, int grade) {
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "name:" + this.name + "grade:" + this.grade;
    }
}

public static void main(String[]args) {
    Student s1 = new Student("Jason", 73);
    Student s2 = new Student("Ricky", 64);
    Student s3 = new Student("Mark", 53);
    String[] names = {s1.getName(), s2.getName(), s3.getName()};
}
```

Comment: `new String[]` is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an array of `String` and set its values like this:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
           Student s1=new Student("Jason",73);
           Student s2=new Student("Ricky",64);
           Student s3=new Student("Mark",53);

           String[] studentNamesArray = {s1.name, s2.name, s3.name};
    }
}
```

Make sure your `name` property is accesible, if not you should do it through a getter:

`public string getName() { 
     return this.name
}`

in your `Student` class.

Answer (score 0):

What about the next:

```
String[] arrayNames = {s1.name, s2.name, s3.name}
```

Please double check that your name attribute is accessible. Usually you can do a getter for it ( public String getName() { return this.name } ), or declare it public. Be aware of the default access modifier / access modifiers in general : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html .